# Drupal 6 Add Webform Programmatically

Tags: hooks, webforms

I'm trying to add a new component or populate an existing hidden component on a web form programmatically.  I found this:

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.module/function/_webform_client_form_add_component/6

However I have not found any hooks, which would be the preferred way to do this.  I'm essentially just checking to see if there is a hook or how to access that function in a custom module if no hook exists.

Answer (score 0):

A webform is simply a node so the rough process of doing this would be to node_load() your particular node, add your components array to the $node->components[] array and then execute a node_save(). There is some [documentation here](https://drupal.org/node/2030697) that fleshes out how to programmatically add a webform, your code would look something like this:

```
$node = node_load(YOUR NODE ID);
$components = $components = array(); #YOUR COMPONENTS ARRAY
$node->webform = array(
      'components' => $components,
);
node_save($node);
```